# How can I Hide TabBar in specific Views, in iOS 15 using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tabbar, navigationview, ios15

I need my `TabBar` to disappear if I click on a `NavigationLink`.
I know you can achieve that in iOS 14 with the following code:

```
 NavigationView{
        TabView{
            View1().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("Home")
            }
        }
    }
```

And `View1`:

```
struct View1: some View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("New Page without the Tabbar")) {
            Text("Link")
        }
    }
}
}
```

But somehow this don't works in iOS 15...
Are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Could you just use a `fullScreenCover` or `sheet` to present the destination instead of a `NavigationLink`? Why fight the system?

Answer (score -2):

You could try using only one `NavigationView`, like in this example:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                View1().tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        // ---> here no NavigationView
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("New Page without the Tabbar")) {
            Text("Link")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer works well for me with the code provided, 
the TabBar disappears when I click on the NavigationLink, 
and this is what the question is about for ios 15. 
Tested on ios 15 and macCatalyst 12 on real devices, using macos 12.1 beta, Xcode 13.1.
Does this not work for someone? or why the down vote?

Comment: There is a problem: You can only set one Navigationtitle per NavigationView. That means if the TabBar contains 3 Tabs, they have all the same Heading / Toolbar.

Comment: As @Max said, this isn't working if the TabBar has multiple different Tabs with Different Headings :(

Comment: humm, a bit confused here, @Max is talking about `...one Navigationtitle per NavigationView..`, 
and you talk about `TabBar has multiple different Tabs with Different Headings`.
Could you show us an example code that replicate your issue with the features you require.